# A book from the late 70s or early 80s?

Tags: story-identification

When I was a teenager (which would have been the mid 80s), I read a series that I really enjoyed, but I can't recall the name of or any of the major details of. It seems like it was set in Louisiana or a bayou of some sort. It had some romance in it, but that was not the main focus. Several of the characters mutated into these creatures that lived in the muddy waters. Does this sound familiar to anyone? I'd like to re-read this series if I could ever find it again.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: The Blackwater series from Michael McDowel?